# Normalization of SQL Server database and multiple dropdown menues in custom user profile

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, database-normalization

Web application in ASP.NET MVC 3 (SQL Server 2012 database).

After normalization of database I have three database tables for user profile and profile management system.

**First table** contains user profiles

Structure:

```
UserId      int (primary key)
Ethnicity   int
Height      int
HairColor   int
...
```

Sample data:

```
1  1  2  1  3
2  1  3  2  4
```

**Second table** contains list of profile fields

Structure:

```
FieldId     int
FieldName   nvarchar(20)
```

Sample data:

```
1 - Ethnicity
2 - Height
3 - HairColor
```

**Third table** contains list of profile fields options (DropDownList options for each field of profile)

Structure:

```
OptionId    int
OptionName  nvarchar(30)
FieldId     int (external key to FieldId of second table)
```

Sample data:

```
1 - Caucasian - 1
2 - Asian - 1
3 - Hispanic - 1
... 
1 - 4"5 - 2
2 - 4"6 - 2
```

I can make 1 request to db for formation of dropdown list in the html page, all clear...

But, when I need to request the member profile I need make two requests and process data in application for linking numbers in UserProfile table with options of ProfileFieldsOptions table...

I can not make one complex request with Inner Join or another option.

Now, question:

Maybe you know more simple way to make such structure in SQL Server for ASP.NET MVC 3?

Key requirement:

1. Profile Fields and Profile Fields Options are needed to save in database.

Thanks, Igor.

Comment: I think specific tables with Ethinicity options, HairColor options, and Height interval options would be just fine. Also, are you sure you want to register height as an interval, not as a number of centimeters for example?

Comment: This is not an interval. This is foots and inches.) About options I answered in bottom. I deleted second and third tables. Now these options are describing in code as constants...

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved by relocation of profile fields options from third table to the `Dictionary<int, string>`, deleting of second table and using for dropdown something like this:

in controllers/classes/models I use class BaseConstants, which consist of public dictionaries:

```
public Dictionary<int, string> Ethnicity = new Dictionary<int, string>()
    {{1, "Caucasian"}, {2, "Black"}, ...};
```

and in view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Item, 
    new SelectList((Dictionary<int, string>)ViewBag.Items,"Key", "Value"), 
    "--Select--")
```

Comment: You switched now from a situation where almost everything is database rows and can change on the fly without recompilation of the code to one where even the options are compiled in code. And the database tables will be less readable without the code present to explain what the integers mean. Questions therefore: How and how often do you expect the options and the fields to change in the future? And will you wish to query the database for users based on values of these fields?

Comment: I do not change these options. And query: user select option from list, but on server post number value of item. This number I use for query.

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate table for each field's options. So separate tables called Ethnicities, Heights, HairColors.
Let your ASP.Net code query this table to retrieve the values for the dictionary you speak of.

Advantages are that

- the database will be more readable without the code, since you can join the option integer to its description
- options can be added (and perhaps even deprecated) without recompilation of the code
- you can enforce consistency of the data using foreign key constraints

Comment: You'll initially have to retrieve the option lists on startup of the application. You can join the descriptions of the options if you like, and that may be handy if you wish to fill a grid view with a list of users. Databases are good at joining data, it won't give you performance headaches.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I will have additional request to database (in more simply case - 20 Left Join)? I have been searched solve, what do not increase number of sql requests. I did not find it.

Comment: Yes, I can request these options once per session and save it in cache, for example. If I want to fill grid of users (and I make this) I write something like '_authInf.gender = bc.Gender[userSession.Member.Gender];' where userSession.Member.Gender - is a number value in db and Gender - Dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

If the options never change, use an enum for each of them.

- They'll have descriptive names when debugging.
- The properties will be typed so you keep some form of consistency. It will prevent accidental swaps from one field to the other or the filling in invalid option number for a field.

LINQ to SQL can handle enums just fine if you should wish to use it.

Comment: Enum do not allow the member names with spaces ("word1 word2").

Comment: Neither do integers *wink* You can give them a description attribute though, if you wish.